# Scrapy recursive crawl and take data from each page

Tags: python, recursion, scrapy

A series of json pages are linked with each other by the last id on that page. The url of the page is `example.com/20/id`
So I want to crawl the first page, **save data**, take the last id of that page and crawl the other page: `example.com/40/new_id` And so on, every time there will be 20 results. I don't know how many pages there are so I'll stop when there is no id.

This should be a simple recursion but I'm not sure how to do it and save the data in the same time. I'm confused about this bit:

```
yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse)
```

which in my opinion should recurse until there is no id, but instead it runs only 2 times.

```
import scrapy
import json
import logging
from w3lib.url import add_or_replace_parameter
import re
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'myspider'
    start_urls = ['https://www.example/0/1234']

    def parse(self, response): # check if there is an id
        data = json.loads(str(response.body, 'utf-8'))
        dataLength = len(data)
        page = 0
        if data[dataLength - 1]["id"]:
            page += 20
            url = add_or_replace_parameter(response.url, 'after', data[dataLength - 1]["id"])
            url = re.sub(r"([0-9]){1,9}(?=\?)", str(page), url) # build the new url
            yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse_page) #save data
            yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse) #do it again with the new url recursively, this bit doesn't work

        yield from self.parse_page(response) # do it for the first page

    def parse_page(self, response):
        data = json.loads(str(response.body, 'utf-8'))
        for item in data:
            finalData = {"language": item["languageName"]}
            yield finalData
```

running in console `scrapy runspider scrap_kaggle.py -o file.csv -t csv` only saves the first 2 urls in the csv file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I would like to explain why you only get two response. You have a logical error: in `parse` function, you initialize `page=0`, so that the following request will always be `page=20`, no more pages are followed.

Then I would like to give you some suggestions, because your logical of recursive crawling is a little mass. According to the [scrapy spider docs](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.parse):

> parse(response)
>   This is the default callback used by Scrapy to process downloaded responses, when their requests don’t specify a callback.
>
> The parse method is in charge of processing the response and returning scraped data and/or more URLs to follow. Other Requests callbacks have the same requirements as the Spider class.
>
> This method, as well as any other Request callback, ***must return an iterable of Request and/or dicts or Item objects***.

(Note the bold part I marked). This means that `parse` function itself can do two operations: parsing to items (in your case saving operation) and following the next request (in your case, the recursion operation). Thus you do not need two different `parse` functions.

Finally, I would like to provide a pseudo code to explain the idea. Please make sure that the next request URL can be correctly built. I cannot test the code which is your responsibility:

```
import scrapy
import json
import logging
from w3lib.url import add_or_replace_parameter
import re
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'myspider'
    start_urls = ['https://www.example/0/1234']

    def parse(self, response): # check if there is an id
        data = json.loads(str(response.body, 'utf-8'))
        # SAVE ITEMS OPERATION
        for item in data:
            finalData = {"language": item["languageName"]}
            yield finalData

        dataLength = len(data)
        # YOU NEED TO DETERMINE THE PAGE NUMBER TO BUILD NEXT REQUEST URL
        page = GET_PREV_PAGE #get the previous page number by response.url
        if data[dataLength - 1]["id"]:
            page += 20
            url = add_or_replace_parameter(response.url, 'after', data[dataLength - 1]["id"])
            url = re.sub(r"([0-9]){1,9}(?=\?)", str(page), url) # build the new url
            # SEND NEXT REQUEST, THE RECURSION OPERATION
            yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse)
```

As you can see, both saving operation and following operation can be put in one `parse` function. The most important part of the following operation is to determine the URL of next request. For your case, you can determine it by parsing the response data and response URL. In the cases that you need more information to determine the next URL, you could put these data into `meta` of request and then retrieve by the `meta` of response, check [scrapy request and response](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html). For example, when yielding request, you may:

```
yield Request(url, meta=dict(page=CURRENT_PAGE_ID)
```

And in your `parse` function, when handling the response, you can retrive this meta data to build the next request:

```
page = response.meta['page']
next_page = page + 20
```

This is just for complicated scenario. In you case, the page is easy to get, you don't need to.

Hope this would be helpful.
Thanks.